# SQL add column with numeric range limitation

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add a column that contains a number between 10 and 180 and defaults to 30. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```sql
ALTER TABLE avisos 
    ADD (tiempo_empleado NUMBER(3,0) CHECK
((tiempo_empleado <= (10)) AND (tiempo_empleado >= (180))) DEFAULT
(30) );
```

This is the error message (translated):

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Are you getting an error or unexpected results? Either way, please share what the error is or what the unexpected results are.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a row" that has a default value? *Columns* have a default value, not a row.

Comment: ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho. Sorry i have SQL server in spanish

Comment: That is an Oracle error (though not in English, so you need to translate it), but you've tagged [[tag:sql-server]] here, @juanrangel . SQL Server and Oracle are completely different products. I suspect you are trying to use Transact-SQL syntax on Oracle, rather than PL/SQL and wondering why it isn't working; it's not working because it's the wrong dialect. Kind of like trying to use VB.Net in a C# application; the langanges are both .Net languages, but they are not the same.

Comment: the parenthesis after the `ADD` is wrong and then also the last one

Comment: Sorry about calling it row. i've been wake up for a long time and i start to feel tired

Comment: In Oracle `default` [should be placed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/column_definition.html) before a constraint: `column [ datatype [ COLLATE column_collation_name ] ]
  [ SORT ] [ VISIBLE | INVISIBLE ]
  [ DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] expr | identity_clause ]
  [ ENCRYPT encryption_spec ]
  [ { inline_constraint }...
  | inline_ref_constraint
  ]`

Comment: YES. that was the problem THANKS SOO MUCH!!!

Comment: ALTER TABLE avisos ADD tiempo_empleado NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT(30) CHECK ((tiempo_empleado >= (10)) and (tiempo_empleado <= (180)));

Answer (score 0):

```
> ALTER TABLE avisos ADD tiempo_empleado NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT(30) CHECK
> ((tiempo_empleado >= (10)) and (tiempo_empleado <= (180)));
> 
> >
```